# Is the ESB Toolkit 2.1 a fully supported Microsoft product?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.1

Is the ESB Toolkit 2.1 a fully supported Microsoft product?

As in, there are hot fixes, patches, etc. released

Or is it a "sample"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fully supported by Microsoft. For more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd876606.aspx . Version 2.2 is also part of BizTalk 2013+ product installation itself.

Comment: Are there any updates/patches for it? ... BizTalk 2010 is up to CU6, adapters are up to CU3, but Toolkit 2.1 ??

Comment: No there are no updates to 2.1, The only update is to version 2.2 as part of BizTalk 2013 and 2013 on wards updates will be part of BizTalk CU release.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you update ESB 2.1 to 2.2/2.3 on a BizTalk 2010, or is limited to a specific version of BizTalk 2.1 -> 2010, 2.2 -> 2013, 2.3 -> 2013 R2

Comment: 2.2 and 2.3 versions are not available separately. They are part of BizTalk 2013 and BizTalk 2013 R2 product installation. I would not recommend to do it. Also there are not many new features in 2.2 and 2.3 except configuration aspect of it, which is lot easier compare to 2.1